# Watt output of radio station

Tags: antenna, radio, output, watts, amplitude-modulation

I was wondering how many watts an AM radio station outputs, and if I can calculate the watts on a tuned antenna by this equation:

[image: Equation]

Where Win = the watts input for the antenna, Wout = the watts output for the radio station, r = distance from the transmitter, and Y = how much rf the antenna gets from that square metre (I'm expecting Y to be like 0.1% or something because it's a pretty small antenna).

Comment: Which radio station? Some are hundreds of kW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple answer.  Working from ((old)) memory, transmitter output power ranges from 5 kW to over 50 kW.  Then the antenna has a shaped radiation pattern (after all, why waste power radiating upward?); it is not a simple point source radiator that so many formulae are based on.  Then you get into multi-antenna phased arrays for serious directionality.

Most radio stations have a website and a Wikipedia page.  Between the two you should be able to find out the basics for stations near you: transmitter power and ERP - effective radiated power.

Comment: Going from lyrics to popular songs about the border radio days, I think 50kW is about right for the top end. Although I did find one reference to a 150kW station. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XEPRS-AM

Comment: The FCC has a query page for AM stations: https://www.fcc.gov/media/radio/am-query

Comment: Transmitter output powers start much lower than 5 kW, with many 1 kW stations and a handful even lower. If the 5th column starts with ND, it's nondirectional, so you can model it as a quarter-wave monopole. If it's DA, a directional antenna, you have more work, and if you want to dig even deeper you can find out ground conductivities too.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt The border radio stations are not under the purview of the FCC.